# URL Rewrite on IIS always fail when change the pattern

Tags: c#, regex, iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to work in a rewrite problem, but its my first time and I guess I'm doing something very wrong.

A few users of our portal, try to navigate typing https://www.dudalina.proveagora.com instead the right one https://dudalina.proveagora.com. We have the SSL only for *.proveagora.com, so I started to try a redirect on the users who type the wrong url.
Here, the print of rewrite working great:
[image]

but, some users type https:// and some users type http://. By this way, I've tried to change the pattern.

[image]

I dont know why, but using the second pattern, the url https://www.dudalina.proveagora.com doesnt redirect anymore.

Just to explain a little more, the dudalina part is dynamic too. Dudalina is the store name, and it will change accordingly with store. So, we can have latter something like http://bestbuy.proveagora.com or anything else and this patterns much works with all the options.

I know, the user cant type www.bestbuy.proveagora.com but they do, and we need to make it works! :(

Any help?

**EDIT**

xml Web.Config

```
     <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RemoveWWWPrefix" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(https\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.)?(proveagora\.com){1}(\/.*)?$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://dudalina.proveagora.com" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Can you post the result from the `web.config` file? Your ultimate goal is to avoid any user to reach `*.dudalina.proveagora.com` with https and if it happens, to redirect them to `dudalina.proveagora.com` keeping the https protocol, is that right?

Comment: @cheesemacfly you're right! I will post the xml web.config on the post! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<rule name="RemoveWWWPrefix" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.+\.)proveagora\.com$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^dudalina\.proveagora\.com$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://dudalina.proveagora.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

What it will check is that the protocol used is `HTTPS` and that the subdomain of `proveagora.com` is present and different from `dudalina`.

If that's the case, it redirects to `https://dudalina.proveagora.com`

Comment: can we do that dynamic? if dudalina is other thing like cheesemacfly, I'll need to redirect to http|https://cheesemacfly.proveagora.com
how can we do that??

Comment: Do you mean having the `dudalina` part being dynamic in the condition and redirect rule so you need to only change it in one place?

Comment: I read about reference group. Something like {R:1} {R:2}, etc. So, at match url I wrote my own rules, separating groups. The first part I got is dudalina. Until there is ok. But with groups, the rules never work. On the action tag, I can use {R:1} referencing the first regex group of my pattern by the {R:1}. Like my second image. Its like I read about on blogs, but nothings works. The dudalina can be other name. Dudalina is the store name, and any store can use our plataform of ecommerce!

Comment: `{R:1}` is called a back reference. If you want to back reference something from the conditions, you can use `{C:1}`. I am not sure if that answers your question tho.